# Equivalent definitions of a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

There are several definitions of a projective module. For example,

1) An $R$-module $P$ is projective if for every epimorphism $f : M \rightarrow P$ there exist a homomorphism $g : P \rightarrow M$ such that $f \circ g = id_P$.

2) An $R$-module $P$ is projective if given homomorphisms $h:P \rightarrow N$, $f : M \rightarrow N$, where $f$ is an epimorphism, there exists a homomorphism $g: P \rightarrow M$ such that $f \circ g = h$.

Proving that 2) => 1) is easy: just choose $N = P$ and $h = id_P$. But how to prove the converse, i.e. 1) => 2) ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the fiber product $X$ of $P$ and $M$ along $N$. What can you say about this commutative square?

Alternate hint: Pick generators for $P$: we can choose a sequence $0\to K \to R^i\to P\to 0$ which is exact. Then (why?) this reduces to solving the problem for free modules.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know fiber products. I was wondering, is there is simple method like choosing the generators of P, and then showing that something holds.

Comment: I would really recommend looking at the fiber product way of doing this- it's very short, elegant, and intuition for fiber products is important in much of algebra. That said, there are certainly other ways to solve it- consider $R^i\to P\to 0$ for some appropriately large $i$, and reduce the problem to free modules (by split exactness of the sequence $0\to K\to R^k\to P\to 0$). This is tedious and somewhat clunky, but if you want to avoid learning anything new, you can certainly do it.

Comment: In other words, $X:=\{(p,m)\mid h(p)=f(m)\}\ \subseteq P\times M$, and show that the projection $X\to P$ is epic.